# Question from $p$-adic HodgeTheory, linear algebra data

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, hodge-theory

I want to understand the definition $2.1.4$ of $\text{Mod}_{\mathscr{O}}^{\varphi}$ category in the pages $4$-$5$ in the $p$-adic Hodge Theory survey paper [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=5B860D7F5133687FBFF3CA0D66469043?doi=10.1.1.649.5188&rep=rep1&type=pdf), by Brian Conrad.

The map $\varphi_{\mathcal{M}}: \mathcal{M} \to \mathcal{M}$ is $\varphi_{\mathscr{O}}$-semilinear and injective.

In page $5$, it says that " a $\varphi_{\mathscr{O}}$-semilinear operator $\varphi_{\mathcal{M}}: \mathcal{M} \to \mathcal{M}$ is injective if its $\mathscr{O}$-linearisation $$1 \otimes \varphi_{\mathcal{M}}: \varphi_{\mathscr{O}}^{*} \mathcal{M}=\mathscr{O} \otimes_{\mathscr{O},\varphi_{\mathscr{O}}} \mathcal{M} \to \mathcal{M}$$ is injective.

**My Question:**

$(1)$ What does mean by $\mathscr{O}$-linearisation of $\varphi_{\mathcal{M}}$ ?

$(2)$ The map $1 \otimes \varphi_{\mathcal{M}}$ act as an identity on $\mathscr{O}$, why is so ?

$(3)$  Why we denote $\varphi_{\mathscr{O}}^{*} \mathcal{M}=\mathscr{O} \otimes_{\mathscr{O},\varphi_{\mathscr{O}}} \mathcal{M}$ ?

please help me by explaining those

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I always find this notation also a bit confusing and incomplete. Let me spell out, regarding 1. and 2., the construction of linearization explicitly:

$\varphi: M \rightarrow M$ is an $\varphi_O$-semilinear map, meaning that the compatibility with the scalar multiplication is somewhat "twisted", i.e. one has $\varphi(am)=\varphi(a)\cdot \varphi(m), \;a \in O, m \in M$ (rather than the "usual" linearity "$\varphi(am)=a\varphi(m)$"). This can cause some problems, for example, the image $\varphi(M)$ is not an $O$-submodule of $M$ in general.

For that reason, it is good to associate some "actually linear" map to $\varphi,$ hence the name linearization. The way to do it is as follows:

Consider $_O O_\varphi$, that is, $O$ as the $O$-bimodule whose left multiplication is the usual one but whose right multiplication is given by viewing $O$ as an $O$-algebra via the ring homomorphism $\varphi: O \rightarrow O$. That is, one has, for $x\in O$ and a scalar $a \in O,$ $a\cdot x=ax$ but $x \cdot a=x\varphi(a)$. Then there is an actually $O$-bilinear map
\begin{align*}
_O O_\varphi\times M & \longrightarrow M \\
(a, m) &\longmapsto a \varphi(m),
\end{align*}

and so this induces an $O$-linear (with respect to scalars acting on the left, i.e. utilizing the left action of $_O O_{\varphi}$) map $_O O_{\varphi} \otimes_{O}M \rightarrow M$, given by $a \otimes m \mapsto a \varphi(m)$. This is the linearization of $\varphi$. From the explicit description, you can kind of see why the map is described by $1\otimes \varphi_M$.

Comment: In the second para, it should be $\varphi(a m)=\varphi_{O}(a) \cdot \varphi(m)$

Comment: Sure. I am purposefully surpressing it. Since $a$ is a scalar, there is really no other $\varphi$ in the picture that could apply.

Comment: It is ok. Thanks

Comment: Can you please look at  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3894175/does-mathfraks-left-frac1u-right-p-wedge-and-widehat-mathf question ?

Answer (score 2):

(1) He means that map
$$1 \otimes \varphi_{\mathcal{M}}: \varphi_{\mathscr{O}}^{*} \mathcal{M}=\mathscr{O} \otimes_{\mathscr{O},\varphi_{\mathscr{O}}} \mathcal{M} \to \mathcal{M}$$
which could also be written as
$$id_{\mathscr{O}} \otimes \varphi_{\mathcal{M}}: \varphi_{\mathscr{O}}^{*} \mathcal{M}=\mathscr{O} \otimes_{\mathscr{O},\varphi_{\mathscr{O}}} \mathcal{M} \to \mathcal{M}$$

and explicitly is given by

$$\sum_i a_i \otimes m_i \mapsto \sum_i a_i \cdot \varphi_{\mathcal{M}}(m_i).$$

Note that this is well-defined because 1) in the tensor product, we have (EDIT: corrected) $a \otimes b m = a \cdot \varphi_{\mathscr{O}}(b)\otimes m $, and 2) we have $\varphi_{\mathcal{M}}(am) = \varphi_{\mathscr{O}}(a)\cdot \varphi_{\mathcal{M}}(m)$ because that is what $\varphi_{\mathcal{M}}$ being $\varphi_{\mathscr{O}}$-semilinear means.

Note that this map is indeed $\mathscr{O}$-linear in the sense that e.g.

$$(1 \otimes \varphi_{\mathcal{M}}) \left( b\cdot \sum_i a_i \otimes m_i\right) = b \cdot\left((1 \otimes \varphi_{\mathcal{M}}) ( \sum_i a_i \otimes m_i) \right)$$

so it is "a linear version of $\varphi_{\mathcal{M}}$". For example if $\mathcal{M}$ is a free module of finite rank, the matrices representing the semilinear map $\varphi_{\mathcal{M}}$ and the linear map $1 \otimes \varphi_{\mathcal{M}}$ are "the same".

(2) I do not know what you mean by that map "acting as the identity on $\mathscr{O}$" because it does not act on $\mathscr{O}$ or anything that canonically identifies with $\mathscr{O}$. If by $\mathscr{O}$ here you mean the first factor in the tensor product (which, however, is not a subset of the teesor product), then, well, it acts as identity there by definition.

(3) $\varphi_{\mathscr{O}}^{*} \mathcal{M}$ naturally identifies with the [extension of scalars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_rings#Extension_of_scalars) of the $\mathscr{O}$-module $\mathcal{M}$ via the ring homomorphism $\varphi_{\mathscr{O}}: \mathscr{O} \rightarrow \mathscr{O}$, and that is often described with that notation with the asterisk. I think this notation, in turn, was chosen to be reminiscent of pullbacks, see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/extension+of+scalars. I believe however that understanding the reasons for certain notations is secondary in understanding the actual theory here.

Comment: Thank you much indeed

Comment: Yes I meant exactly that in question (2), which you explained well

Comment: Finally, in your last paragraph, you said about extension of scalars. But I see the coefficient ring $\mathscr{O}$ remains same, so how it is actually extending the scalars ?  Are you saying that we are interchanging $\varphi_{\mathcal{M}}$ by $\varphi_{\mathscr{O}}$ ?

Comment: Indeed this might look strange on first encounter: When one first learns scalar extension, one usually has something like a vector space $V$ over a field $K$, and then some field extension $K \subset L$, and one looks at $L \otimes_K V$. But learn that in a more general case, instead of the inclusion $K \hookrightarrow L$, one can have *any homomorphism between rings* $\sigma: R\rightarrow S$; and in our case, it happens that the homomorphism $\varphi_{\mathscr{O}}$ has $\mathscr{O}$ both as domain and codomain. It's more a "twist" of the scalars with a homomorphism than literal "extension".

Comment: Thank you very much