# Does $\mathfrak{S}\left[\frac{1}{u} \right]_{(p)}^{\wedge}$ and $\widehat{\mathfrak{S}\left[\frac{1}{u} \right]_{(p)}}$ mean the same thing?

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra, p-adic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

In page $24$ of [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=9C5634193245F37CB605F8B5363F66F5?doi=10.1.1.649.5188&rep=rep1&type=pdf) survey paper on $\text{$p$-adic Hodge Theory}$, by Brian Conrad, I am having confusion understanding the following notation:

He denoted by $\mathscr{O}_{\varepsilon}:=\mathfrak{S}\left[\frac{1}{u} \right]_{(p)}^{\wedge}$, where $p$ is the uniformizer, i.e., $(p)$ is the prime or maximal ideal. Clearly the symbol $\wedge$ means he is taking $p$-adic completion of $\mathfrak{S}\left[\frac{1}{u} \right]$ with respect to $(p)$.

I have attached the page as well:
[image]

**My question:**

$(1)$ Does he mean to take localisation of $\mathfrak{S} \left[ \frac{1}{u}\right]$ at the prime ideal $(p)$  and then taking completion $\wedge$ of $\mathfrak{S}\left[\frac{1}{u} \right]_{(p)}$  ?

$(2)$ Does $\mathfrak{S}\left[\frac{1}{u} \right]_{(p)}^{\wedge}$ and $\widehat{\mathfrak{S}\left[\frac{1}{u} \right]_{(p)}}$ mean the same thing?

Please help with these two questions.

Comment: What is $\mathfrak{S}\left[\frac{1}{u} \right]$ how did you construct it

Comment: Yes to both, I would say.

Comment: @reuns, $\mathfrak{S}:=W(\kappa)[[u]]$, where $W(\kappa)$ is the ring of witt-vectors. Then I think $\mathfrak{S} \left[ \frac{1}{u} \right]$ to be the localisation of $\mathfrak{S}$ by $S=\{u^n\}$, i.e., $\mathfrak{S} \left[ \frac{1}{u} \right]=\varinjlim \mathfrak{S}u^{-n}.$